# How to properly plot dataframe with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

[image]I'm trying to plot a dataframe with two columns:

```
    Compound_ID,Averages
  0  M0001,0.75
  1  M0002,0.87
  2  M003,0.45
```

Instead of showing the 'Compound_ID' on the x axis it is showing the index. When I explicitly try to plot, it raises and error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('teste.csv')
plt.plot(df['Averages'], df['Compound_ID'])
plt.show()


AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'
```

It is probably something easy to solve, but can someone take a look at my code?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('teste.csv')
plt.plot(df['Averages'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437305/how-to-fix-attributeerror-series-object-has-no-attribute-find)

Comment: Are you after: `df.plot.bar(x='Compound_ID', y='Averages', rot=0)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
plt.plot(df['Averages'])
plt.xticks(range(len(df['Compound_ID'])) , df['Compound_ID'])
```

This way you plot xticks separately. The first element is numerical indexes, second - names.